# internet not running on ubuntu server 10.04

Tags: 10.04, networking, server

I am not able to connect to the internet via VM Virtaul Box.
These are my configurations

[image]

But i can ping to the sever via window CMD
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. You don't need to manually specify ip address to the virtual system.

See your windows host receive connectivity using the settings configured as it is. Now windows host serves as server to linux guest. VBox takes care of it automatically.

So remove the ip Address assigned in ubuntu guest.

Make sure virtualbox Ethernet is enabled and NAT is chosen.

[image: vbox network]

Comment: should I empty the /etc/resolv.conf also ?

Comment: keep it as it was in fresh system.